# Docker read file from local system when container is running

Tags: docker

My `Dockerfile` runs a python script that requires reading in a text file from my local machine.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM fedeg/python-vim:2
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY file.txt /data/file.txt
CMD ["python", "run.py"]
```

In the run.py there is a function that reads in the text file:

```
def read_file(filename):
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(filename)]
    return lines
```

I was wondering if i were to pass this image to someone else and they run it, will the file.txt already be saved inside the image or will docker be able to look for that file.txt in that person's local machine when the image is started?

What i want is for docker to look for the name `file.txt` on any machines where the image is running on so it can work on the contents of the other file.txt instead of the file.txt i provided from my local machine.

Answer (score 12):

As @herm pointed out by building the container the way you did, the file.txt is stored inside the container.

To achieve what you want, remove the COPY from the Dockerfile and instead mount the folder containing file.txt on the host machine with the -v option at run time:

```
docker run -v /folder/with/file:/data image_name
```

where /folder/with/file is the path to the folder containing file.txt and image_name is the name of your docker container.

The content of /data in the running container will now be the content of the /folder/with/file folder.

EDIT:

You could also mount just the file instead:

```
docker run -v /folder/with/file/file.txt:/data/file.txt image_name
```

However note that this might give problems if you need to edit the file. See [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume) "Mount a host file as a data volume"

> Note: Many tools used to edit files including vi and sed --in-place may result in an inode change. Since Docker v1.1.0, this will produce an error such as “sed: cannot rename ./sedKdJ9Dy: Device or resource busy”. In the case where you want to edit the mounted file, it is often easiest to instead mount the parent directory.

Comment: if my current folder is `~/Desktop/docker_test/work` and the text file is in `~/Desktop/docker_test` will the syntax be like this: `docker run -v ~/Desktop/docker_test/work:/data image_name`

Comment: Not quite... you want to mount the folder with the file.txt so: `docker run -v ~/Desktop/docker_test:/data image_name`

Comment: what about the filename? `docker run -v ~/Desktop/docker_test/file.txt:/data image_name` i mounted the folder but then the python error is that it cannot find file

Comment: Thank you very much for this! As a note for Windows users, be aware to use double back slashes for Windows paths, and simple forward slashes for container's paths. 
Example: "docker run -v C:\\some_folder\\spreadsheet_source.csv : /app/spreadsheet_copy.csv"

Comment: `docker run --rm -ti -v c:/var/myappfolder/tinput:/input app.company.com/container_basic:latest` I used forward slashes for Windows Docker Desktop as given...

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is saved inside the image.

An image contains all the change you describe in the dockerfile. Anything that happens in there is part of the image and will be usable by someone you give the image to.

Anything that happens on your container which you create with docker run or docker service does not effect your image. If you wanted that you could docker commit a container to turn it into a new image.

Comment: so if someone else has the image, and they have a different file.txt that they want to run, how do they replace that file.txt already in my image with theirs?

Comment: If the idea is that anyone can add their file you should use a mounted volume and not have the data in the image. You can still mount a volume to the container volume and the data you mounted will be used.

Comment: I just remembered you can also use [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) to copy files between container and host

Comment: There is a link to the documentation so please help yourself or ask a more concrete question.